# How to get single field on $lookup?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to do a "left join" with three collections to get a value from the third collection, but I'm not getting it as a single value.

Example:

Collection 1:

```
{ socialNetworkId: 1, name: "Orkut"}
```

Collection 2:

```
{ userId: 1, socialNetworkId: 1, imgId: 100, user: "George" }
{ userId: 2, socialNetworkId: 1, imgId: 100, user: "Flanders" }
```

Collection 3:

```
{ imgId: 100, img: "url" }
```

When I do something like:

```
db.socialNetwork.aggregate(
    { $match : {"socialNetworkId" : "1"} },
    {
        $lookup : {
            from : "users",
            localField : "socialNetworkId",
            foreignField : "socialNetwork.socialNetworkId",
            as : "users"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup : {
            from : "images",
            localField : "users.imgId",
            foreignField : "imgId",
            as : "images"
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: (
            {
              "users.img": "$images.img"
            }
        )
    },
    {
        $project : {
            "images": 0
        }
    }
);
```

I get:

```
{
  socialNetworkId: 1,
  "users" : [
    { 
      userId: 1, 
      socialNetworkId: 1, 
      user: "George",
      **images: [""]**
    },...
  ]
}
```

Is there anyway to get the images as an single value instead an array?

Comment: How do you want to show the images from the array in your output. _"...single value instead an array"_: you mean only one (or first) value in the array?

Comment: @prasad_ one value from the array that refers to the other collection

Comment: Your query doesn't match any data at the `$match` stage. Also, in the first `$lookup` the code `foreignField : "socialNetwork.socialNetworkId"` should be ``foreignField : "socialNetworkId"` `. Please try not to post code without verifying it.